# Riemann curvature tensor

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curvature

Is there another convention for the Riemann curvature tensor than the one I know:

$R^a_{d c b} =d x_a (R( \partial_c, \partial_b) \partial_d)$ ?

Because I have the following "notation" in a paper:

$R^{\ \ \ a}_{dcb}$

and from my calculation this should be $R^{\ \ \ a}_{cbd}$.

Comment: Yes, there are different conventions for the Riemann curvature tensor by different authors.  See the comments to [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/342288)

Comment: A usual trick for me to see which convention they are using is to see how they calculate the Ricci curvature. If you are doing submanifold, Gauss equation also infer the choice.